# Conditions for Residue Limit Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I know this formula is a shortcut to getting the residue of a singularity and I know how to use it (instead of working out the whole series for the n term I need). However on Wikipedia they do not explain why this is true and what the conditions are.

> $$\mathrm{Res}(f,c) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z \to c} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left( (z-c)^{n}f(z) \right).$$

I think $f(z)$ has to be a holonomic function

Answer (score 1):

The word is "holomorphic".  In this case, you need it to be holomorphic in a deleted neighbourhood of $z=c$.  That's the only kind of function for which "residue at $c$" is defined.

The formula is true if $f$ has a pole of order $ \le n$ at $z=c$.  This is easily seen by looking at the Laurent series of $f$ about $z=c$.